# Laravel Artisan Custom Command - Is there a way to make a help context for options?

Tags: php, laravel, command

Does anyone know if there is a way to create a --help context for any particular command options you would create in the signature of a custom artisan command?

I have created an artisan command that can use a {--task=} option. What I wish to provide for a user is a means of them calling up a help description for the option preceding the `--help` boolean flag.

I know you can presently accomplish this in artisan if you do something like this;

```
php artisan make:controller --help
```

whereby this would then show you some help text about the make:controller command.
So, can this be achieved for command options also?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan#input-descriptions - The `protected $signature = '...'` and `protected $description = '...'` will be output and listed if you run `php artisan my-custom-command --help`

Comment: Hi @TimLewis...correct. However, what I was hoping to achieve was a help context that was specific to a particular option. In my case, I wish to display an array of acceptable values that a user can provide for the option in question. In my OP, I specified {--task=} and would like to show the user what values are valid for the task option. Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, you'd provid it in the `protected $signature`, something like `protected $signature = 'my-custom-command {--task : Valid Values: A, B, C}';`. When you run `php artisan my-custom-command --help`, you'll see it listed, like [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jemo2.png). It's not scoped to the single option though, but it should still get the point across to the end user.

Comment: Thank you, @TimLewis! I'll see if I can work with that since the valid values array is fairly large. If you want to make a formal reply...I'll accept that as the accepted answer. Otherwise, I'll just answer it myself and accept that, but would prefer to give you the credit for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--help` command, when run against a Custom Command, will output something like the following:

```
Description:
  // Whatever the value of `protected $description = '...';` is

Usage:
  // Whatever the value of `protected $signature = '...';` is
  // (with additional options truncated)

Options:
  // Additional Options as defined in `protected $signature = '...';`

  // All Default options available to each `php artisan ...` command
  -h, --help            Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi|--no-ansi  Force (or disable --no-ansi) ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

If you define your command as such:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

class MyCutomCommand extends Command {
  protected $signature = 'my-custom-command {--task : Valid Options: A, B, C}';
  protected $description = 'This is a Custom Command';

  public function handle() {
    // Command Logic...
  }
}
```

When you then run `php artisan my-custom-command --help`, you'll see the above, or more specifically:

[image]

In your case, if your valid options is dynamic (or simply too long), you can adjust your code as such:

```php
private $validOptions = ['Long', 'List', 'of', 'Options'];

public function __construct() {
  // $validOptions = DB::table('valid_options')->pluck('name');, etc etc
  
  $this->signature = 'my-custom-command {--task : Valid Options: ' . implode(', ', $this->validOptions) . '}';

  parent::__construct();
}
```

Documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan#input-descriptions